# Dependency chain conflicts for Hibernate and Apache Felix

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi, dependency-management, apache-felix

I understand the concept of OSGi complaining about multiple dependency chains - a package is available more than once and when the importing bundle doesn't specify exactly which version it needs, so the OSGi container can run into the trouble of not knowing what to provide.

Unfortunately I ran into such a problem this week, but both involved bundles are third party bundles, so I can't really influence their imports and exports. Here are the two error messages I get:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve bundle revision org.hibernate.core [28.0] because it is exposed to package 'javax.xml.stream' from bundle revisions com.springsource.javax.xml.stream [23.0] and org.apache.felix.framework [0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.hibernate.core [28.0]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream
  com.springsource.javax.xml.stream [23.0]

Chain 2:
  org.hibernate.core [28.0]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.transform.stax)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.transform.stax; uses:=javax.xml.stream
    export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream
  org.apache.felix.framework [0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3824) 
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)



org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve bundle revision org.hibernate.core [28.0] because it is exposed to package 'javax.xml.stream' from bundle revisions org.apache.felix.framework [0] and com.springsource.javax.xml.stream [23.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.hibernate.core [28.0]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream
  org.apache.felix.framework [0]

Chain 2:
  org.hibernate.core [28.0]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=org.dom4j.io)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.dom4j.io; uses:=javax.xml.stream
  com.springsource.org.dom4j [27.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream)(version>=1.0.1)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream
  com.springsource.javax.xml.stream [23.0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3824)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

When I try and remove `com.springsource.javax.xml.stream` from installed bundles, `com.springsource.org.dom4j` complains about missing package `javax.xml.stream`.

I checked the `MANIFEST.MF` file of `org.apache.felix.framework` because I was really astonished of Felix apparently exporting `javax.xml.stream`, but it contains no such entry. Also the `dom4j` bundle does not reexport the streaming package according to it's manifest.

I'd be really grateful for any tips that could get me closer to answer the question where this dependency chain problem comes from. From my point of view I couldn't find a bundle besides `com.springsource.javax.xml.stream` exporting said package-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often an issue if a package is available in a bundle and also in the bpot classpath (JDK). It is even a bigger issue if that package is wired from another JDK package and also from a bundle directly. In your case the problem is the following:

- javax.xml.transform.stax is available only on the boot classpath (JDK) so hibernate.core wires to that package.
- As javax.xml.transform.stax comes from the boot classpath, it can wire to another package on the boot classpath. It needs javax.xml.stream so it will wire to the package that comes from JDK

We have the chain:

```
hibernate.core -> javax.xml.transform.stax -> javax.xml.stream
```

On the other hand, hibernate.core  wires to javax.xml.stream directly. Probably it even uses a version in the Import-Package section so it cannot wire to the package that comes from JDK.

We have the chain:

```
hibernate.core -> javax.xml.stream
```

This generates a conflict. As hibernate.core uses the *javax.xml.stream* API with the help of *javax.xml.transform.stax*, *hibernate.core* and *javax.xml.transform.stax* should use the same classes of *javax.xml.stream*. However, they do not.

You have a couple of options to solve your problem:

You can install a bundle that contains *javax.xml.transform.stax* package. That package will be able to wire to the *javax.xml.stream* package that comes from the bundle and also hibernate.core can wire to the bundle that contains *javax.xml.transform.stax*. You can pray that the wirings will be always OK.

In my experience, the wires are good after the framework is started. As the package versions are higher in the bundles, they will be preferred when the package is imported from other bundles. However, when the bundles are updated and refreshed at runtime, the wiring often goes wrong. I do not know why, it just happens.

To avoid every issue, I normally exclude those packages from the boot classpath that are also available in bundles.

Your next issue might be that these APIs often use factory classes. When someone uses such a factory, the classloader of the factory class must see the implementation classes, too. I created a [bundle](https://repository.everit.biz/nexus/service/local/repositories/thirdparty/content/org/everit/osgi/bundles/org.everit.osgi.bundles.org.apache.xmlcommons.full/1.4.1-20140120/org.everit.osgi.bundles.org.apache.xmlcommons.full-1.4.1-20140120.jar) that contains all of the xmlcommons packages. It contains all of the xml-apis classes and implementation for them (xerces, xalan, etc). It might be helpful for you. If this bundle solves your problem, please let me know. In that case, I will take the time finally to collect all necessary data (licensing into the pom, sources) and release it to maven-central so it can help others as well.

Comment: Hi Balazs, thanks for your detailed answer. It helped light up the cause. I tried installing a bundle for javax.xml.transform.stax, but that only led to the next package causing problems and messed up my dependencies more and more. As the framework will probably never see bundle updates at runtime the solution would have been fine enough. --- Can you probably provide further information on how I can exclude the packages from the classpath? Can I do this by code or is it some startup configuration?

Comment: It is a startup configuration, you can do this with system properties. Sadly, you cannot do exclusion, but you can define the content of the boot classpath. If you use felix, see the "org.osgi.framework.system.packages" system property at https://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html. The value will be pretty long as you should list every package here that you use from JDK. An example is available at https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-liquibase-bundle/blob/15dcbcef0b4fcf95e7ef413b1720a91ecd83821d/tests/pom.xml#L100

Comment: Alright... I've seen that before, but some parts of me were hoping you'd have a nicer solution somewhere ;) But what counts in the end is that that solved the problem :) I'll dive into the dependencies of the bundles a bit deeper sometimes to maybe clean up that package mess a bit, but at least it works for a start, so thanks a lot! --- Before I forget, your bundle looks really cool! I can't use it for my project because of policy restrictions, but I'm sure it would help a lot of people out there.